# rename series of files which differ in extension within the same directory using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a series of files which differ in extension (for example, `a.txt`, `a.ps`, `a.pdf`, etc.) and would like to copy them to a series of new files with a different name (`b.txt`, `b.ps`, `b.pdf`, etc.), preferably using terminal as I am running all other necessary operations from there. Years ago, I used to be able to do this on a PC from command prompt quite simply with:

```
copy d.* a.*
```

while in the working directory.

I'm having trouble figuring out/finding the corresponding OSX command. Feel like I am missing something obvious here, but just cannot sort it out.

Help much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This command would seem to do what you wish

```
for file in *.* ; do cp $file ${file//a\./b\.} ; done
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789186/4424636) to [Renaming part of a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392768/4424636)

Actually, you could just do:

```
for file in * ; do cp $file ${file//a\./b\.} ; done
```

Note that the `.` has to be escaped using `\.`. This is primarily because your example is a filename of a single letter, which *could* potentially conflict with a letter in the extension.

If your filenames are a bit more explicit, such as `doggy.txt`, `doggy.pdf`, `doggy.xls`, etc., and you want to change them to `feline.txt`, `feline.pdf`, ..., etc., then you could do away with escaping the `.` (and the `.` all together), like so:

```
for file in * ; do cp $file ${file//doggy/feline} ; done
```

---

Note that the commands above will create a ***copy*** of the files, i.e.:

```
% ls
a.pdf   a.txt   a.xls   b.pdf   b.txt   b.xls
```

If you wish to just ***rename*** them, then use `mv` instead:

```
for file in * ; do mv $file ${file//a\./b\.} ; done
```

or

```
for file in * ; do mv $file ${file//doggy/feline} ; done
```

Comment: Also, unless you want to replace *all* matches, you should use `${file/a/b}`, this will also solve the suffix problem.

Comment: Or even `${file/#a/b}` to match from the beginning (`#` plays the same role here as `^`  in `grep`).

Comment: Ah, and apply double quotes, you never know whether people have space characters in their filenames.

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much! Is there a way to make it quicker (maybe with an alias?) and more general? For example, in modeling some data, it's useful for me to make a number of these (dog.* to cat.*, dog.* to bird.* etc. so that I can keep dog.* while testing things with cat.*, bird.* etc.). The dream is something that can take ?.* (where ? will vary, not always dog) and easily make cat.*, bird.*, etc (number will vary). Looking for the OSX version of the PC copy file1.* file2.* , copy file1.* file3.* etc. Thanks again for your quick and helpful reply earlier!